# If the sizes of the two ranges to the algorithm std::mismatch different yields Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've seen on Cppreference a possible implementation of the algorithm `std::mismatch` as:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
std::pair<InputIt1, InputIt2>
mismatch(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2)
{
   while (first1 != last1 && *first1 == *first2) {
      ++first1, ++first2;
   }
   return std::make_pair(first1, first2);
}
```

So if the first range is longer than the second then at some point the off-end iterator in the second range is de-referenced and then increments which yield Undefined Behavior. right? e.g:

```
std::vector<int> v1{24, 10, 81, 7, 57};
std::vector<int> v2{24, 10, 81};
auto p = std::mismatch(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), v2.cbegin()); // UB?
```

- So the elements are equal until `v1` is at `7` and `v2` is `past the last element` so it is de-referenced then incremented which causes UB.
- I think the algorithm must check the second range too whether it is at the end or not at each iteration:

  ```
  first1 != last1 && first2 != last2
  ```
- I think the third and fourth versions are the right ones:

  ```
    template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
    std::pair<InputIt1, InputIt2> mismatch(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2)
    {
        while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2 && *first1 == *first2) {
            ++first1, ++first2;
        }
        return std::make_pair(first1, first2);
    }

    Fourth version

    template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryPredicate>
    std::pair<InputIt1, InputIt2> mismatch(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, BinaryPredicate p)
    {
        while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2 && p(*first1, *first2)) {
            ++first1, ++first2;
        }
        return std::make_pair(first1, first2);
    }
  ```
- Here is the link to the topic on cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch

Comment: If you aren't sure the ranges are the same length, that's wgat the overloads that accept two pairs of begin/end iterators are for.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: So is it safe to compare sequences with different sizes? and how are the overloads that accept different sizes? do you mean template specializations for example?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa They take 4 iterators `[first1,last1)` and `[first2,last2)` algorithms 5,6,7 and 8.  Also _"...If last2 is not provided (overloads (1-4)), it denotes first2 + (last1 - first1)...."_ so that is the contract you must ensuse is true before you call any of 1 to 4.  So range 2 must be at least as long as range 1.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: So you mean if the sizes are not equal then I should pass 4 iterators otherwise I pass only 3?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa You should use the 4 iterator version unless you know for sure that first range is not longer than the range that follows the third argument. If you aren't sure, just always use the 4 iterator version.

Comment: The documentation that the question links to answers the question. Read the text under **Return value**.

Comment: *"I think the third and fourth versions are the right ones:"* -- What do you mean by "right"? The third and fourth versions are right for implementing overloads 5 and 7 respectively, but not for implementing the other overloads. In particular, they cannot be right for overload 1, since overload 1 takes three parameters, the third version takes four, and the fourth version takes five parameters. It seems like your concept of "right" would be better directed at the declarations than the implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ranges are assumed to be identical for the old overloads. From the [MSVC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/algorithm-functions?view=msvc-160#mismatch):

> Use the dual-range overloads in C++14 code because the overloads that only take a single iterator for the second range will not detect differences if the second range is longer than the first range, and will result in undefined behavior if the second range is shorter than the first range

The performance penalty for using the dual-range algorithms is minimal (one extra comparison per loop), and, with random-access iterators, the dual-range std::equals and std::is_permutation are required to return False in constant time if the lengths are different. If you're interested, there's a talk [by MSVC standard library implementer Stephan Lavavej from 2014](https://youtu.be/dTeKf5Oek2c?t=606) at CPPcon discussing the changes, as well as the fact that numeric's 'inner_product' function and the binary version of 'transform' was missed (and still has only the 'range-and-a-half' overload).

If dual-range algorithms are available, they are highly recommended. Only use the other overloads if you know what you're doing and absolutely need the performance (and then usually only with non-random-access iterators, since often compilers optimize the dual-range overloads (for e.g. is_permutation) on random iterators by checking the lengths, then calling the range-and-a-half overload anyway).